# New C# Programmer - Adding two numericUpDown values together?

Tags: c#, numericupdown

I'm fairly new to C# programming.

I am making a program for fun that adds two numbers together, than displays the sum in a message box. I have two numericUpDowns and a button on my form. When the button is pushed I want it to display a message box with the answer.

The problem is, I am unsure how to add the twp values from the numericUpDowns together.

So far, I have this in my button event handler:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this.numericUpDown1.Value + this.numericUpDown2.Value);
    }
```

But obviously, it does not work. It gives me 2 compiler errors:
1. The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string) has some invalid arguments
2. Argument '1': cannot convert decimal to 'string'

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this.numericUpDown1.Value + this.numericUpDown2.Value` is actually evaluating properly to a number, so you're actually very close. The problem is that the `MessageBox.Show()` function, needs a string as an argument, and you're giving it a number.

To convert the result to a string, add `.ToString()` to it. Like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show((this.numericUpDown1.Value + this.numericUpDown2.Value).ToString());
    }
```

For reference, if you want to do more advanced formatting, you'd want to use `String.Format()` instead of `ToString()`. See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx) for more info on how to use `String.Format()`.

Answer (score 2):

This works.

```
    decimal total = this.numericUpDown1.Value + this.numericUpDown2.Value;
    MessageBox.Show(total.ToString());
```

MessageBox.Show expects a string as a parameter (that's the first error message).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show((this.numericUpDown1.Value + this.numericUpDown2.Value).ToString());
    }
```

It takes the values from the numericUpDown components and adds them to get an object of the type `Decimal`. This is then converted to a String, which MessageBox takes.

Answer (score 0):

Now that's easy. [NumericUpDown.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.value.aspx) has a type of Decimal. `Messagebox.Show()` expects a String. All you need to do is

```
MessageBox.Show((this.numericUpDown1.Value + this.numericUpDown2.Value).ToString());
```

to convert the result of the addition to a string.